# WooCommerce product change URL

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I need some help on how I can change WordPress WooCommerce category URL

I want show URL like this

```
https://example.com/category_name/product_name/?attribute_pa_festtype=CATEGORY-SLUG
```

Comment: I believe that the url structure you're looking for can be achieved with wordpress/woocommerce permalinks default behavior. Have you tried fine tuning your permalink settings?

Comment: yes but i can't make it please tell me briefly

Comment: I'd advise changing your question in order to make it clearer. I believe it isn't possible to get the product's `CATEGORY-SLUG` after the `attribute_pa_festtype` as long as you'd normally get the variation slug after it by default.

Comment: I'm really not sure what you're looking after, perhaps I might be wrong, but do you want to "echo" the product's category slug right after the `attribute_pa_festtype` variation query string? One should expect to get the variation slug and not the category slug after it... Please enlighten us.

Answer (score 0):

Under www.example.com/wp-admin/options-permalink.php

There option to change the behavior,see screenshot.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for reply....I know about this setting but i want make custom link https://example.com/category_name/product_name/?attribute_pa_festtype=CATEGORY-SLUG
is it possible throw rewrite_rule if you have any idea about rewrite rule so please guide me